# Star Rating with Facebook Connect?

Tags: facebook, plugins, voting

I would like to add the possibility for users to rate my content - after authenticating with facebook connect.
The rating should be (optionally) posted to the users facebook wall, like comments on an item.

Is there any such thing (like a facebook social plugin) that works out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not any star rating feature in the Facebook connect that you can activate, you will have to code it yourself.